# How to disable MyEclipse visual HTML designer

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

My computer lags for several seconds when I open an HTML file in MyEclipse, or make a major change to a file that's already open.  I suspect that the WYSIWYG part of the visual HTML designer is responsible; is there a way to turn that off but retain the color-coded text editor/formatter?  I also don't care about the "preview" feature, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F12 hides the visual panel

Comment: only hides the current file, not all

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. Go to `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations` and pick the file extension for which you would like to disable/enable the designer. Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make Default MyEclipse Jsp Editor for opening jsp files without Visual Designer
Go to

WIndow > Prefs > General > Text Editors > File Associations

1-Click on File Associations  -

2-select file type for whom you want to change Editor-

3-Select Myeclipse Jsp Editor as default

Same way you can adjust any files types Editors

adjust the default editor for the file types like .jsp, .jspf, .jspx and so on to use the non-visual editor.